# Deleting from a Data Grid View

Tags: winforms, linq-to-sql, datagrid

I have created a windows form application. I want this application to be able to use Linq to SQL to search for a record, and then for that record to be selected from a data grid view and deleted.

The form contains a textbox to enter the parameter, a search button and a delete button and a datagrid.

I have the search part working correctly and the data grid is populated but don't know how to implement clicking on the record in the data grid and deleting it.

**Update - I have solved the solution. Changes have only been made to the btn_Delete_Click event handler so I have included the updated code for his button after the main code.**

```
namespace DeleteForm
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    LinqtoStudentDataContext linqStud = new LinqtoStudentDataContext();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lastName = from stud in linqStud.Students
                       where txtFind.Text == stud.LastName
                       select stud;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = lastName;
    }
}
}
```

Updated code -

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
            //linqStud.Students.DeleteAllOnSubmit();
            linqStud.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Get selected rows from grid, and delete students by id.

Comment: lazyberezovsky - how would I do the selected rows part though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set selection mode of DataGridView to `FullRowSelect`. Next, when assigning DataSource you should call `ToList()` - you can't use query as data source:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lastName = txtFind.Text;
    var students = from stud in linqStud.Students
                   where stud.LastName == lastName
                   select stud;

    dataGridView1.DataSource = students.ToList();
}
```

Get selected rows, and remove databound items (students) from context:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        var student = row.DataBoundItem as Student;
        linqStud.Students.Remove(student);
        linqStud.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```